# How to fire TextBox.TextChanged event on jquery onkeyup?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have asp.net TextBox with ontextchanged event this is search text box in my application.

I have search code in this event. how can I fire this event with the help of j query onkeyup.

If i enter text in text box it will fire ontextchanged without press enter or mouse.

This is an example of event what i need. But i dont know how to fire ontextchanged on this.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/sum-textbox-value-javascript.html

Comment: I think the event for INPUT type="text" would be onchange not ontextchanged.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('#textMessage').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var message =  $('#textMessage').val();
    alert(message);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}); //endTextMessage keyup
```