# Fire an event automatically after barcode scanner input

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a textbox on an asp.net page. I use a barcode scanner to get the barcode number into that textbox. I need to then automaticaly fire an event directly after the text box recieves that input. the only event that is exposed is the TextChanged event which doesnt achieve what i need. I am using c# for the code behind.

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362284/how-to-fire-textbox-textchanged-event-on-jquery-onkeyup

Comment: Perhaps you can explain *why* TextChanged doesn't achieve what you need. Also, if the barcode scanner is a keyboard hook driver, there may be no way for your page to determine that the barcode entry is complete.

Comment: I think they usually send a magic key before and after sending the input.

Comment: @CodeInChaos -- that completely depends on how the scanner is configured.  Every USB scanner that I have worked with comes out of the box simply emulating a keyboard with no special prefix/suffix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `TextChanged` event with `AutoPostBack=true`.

Also ensure that your scanner sends a carriage return after scanning(normally with scanning a code from the manual).